# What is online presence? (Is it the same as gameplay?)

Tags: networking

I was reading the Fortnite 2018 outage [postmortem](https://www.epicgames.com/fortnite/en-US/news/postmortem-of-service-outage-at-3-4m-ccu?sessionInvalidated=true), and it mentions it uses XMPP for **online presence**. Im not sure if this means gameplay or more generally, the presence of Fortnite online, like its websites and social media tools.

The article also mentions it uses XMPP for `presences, commands and various aux data`. Is this 'player presence' and their 'key commands' in the game world?

It also mentions 'presence flow between players'. I have no idea what this could mean.

Comment: Did you [look up XMPP](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMPP) as a starting point? The very first paragraph in that article links to a page [explaining presence](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presence_information).

Comment: I superficially knew what XMPP is, but did not look at the Wikipedia page as I assumed it wasn't highly coupled to presence, it now seems like it is. I looked for online presence though, and didn't get any information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[XMPP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMPP) is an instant messaging protocol. "Presence" in this context means an indicator that another user is offline, afk, available or busy. I never played Fortnite, so I have no first-hand knowledge about what social features this game provides. But the article says:

> We leverage XMPP for the following features: Online presence, Push notifications, Whispers, Group chat - for parties, for team chat and global rooms.

It seems like they are using XMPP to handle a couple social features in the game like showing you which of your friends are online or allowing you to send them text-messages. "Presence flow between players" in this context means receiving real-time notifications when your friends go online or offline.

So as the article says, if the XMPP server has a problem, then the first thing players notice about this is that all their friends appear as offline even though they are not:

> As a result, though people did actually connect to XMPP, the UI showed everyone as offline due to missing presence flow.

Comment: So they aren't using XMPP for communication about player position changes and damage delt? I was trying to find out more about how the actual gameplay system works.

Comment: @BenButterworth The XMPP protocol would be a very odd choice for actual gameplay netcode, especially in a fast-paced game like Fortnite. Unfortunately this website is not the best resource for finding out how existing games work. Our mission is to help you to develop your own games, not to reverse-engineer existing ones.

Comment: I don't actually play fortnite, but took it as an example of a top multiplayer game with lots of traffic. I wanted to know how the gameplay information is transferred between players and servers to see how the top games do it, but its probably not important for my scale of games.